# How to display message wc_print_notice on a custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a snippet I got from https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-check-product-category-cart/ which is:

```php
/* 
 * @snippet       Check if Product Category is in the Cart - WooCommerce
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=72900
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 3.1.2
 */

add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_check_category_in_cart');

function bbloomer_check_category_in_cart() {

// Set $cat_in_cart to false
$cat_in_cart = false;

// Loop through all products in the Cart        
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    // If Cart has category "download", set $cat_in_cart to true
    if ( has_term( 'download', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $cat_in_cart = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Do something if category "download" is in the Cart      
if ( $cat_in_cart ) {

// For example, print a notice
wc_print_notice( 'Category Downloads is in the Cart!', 'notice' );

// Or maybe run your own function...
// ..........

}

}
```

It displays a notice if a product category is in the cart but it display the message via `wc_print_notice` on the cart page. I would like to display this message on a custom theme page template either via a short-code or any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    // modify the function above
    if ( $cat_in_cart )
    {
        $msg = 'Category Downloads is in the Cart!';
        wc_print_notice( $msg, 'notice' );
        return $msg;
    }
    return null;

...

// create a new function for the shortcode
// it can be after the above function
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'myshortcode_func' );
function myshortcode_func( $atts ) {
    return (($msg = bbloomer_check_category_in_cart()) !== null)
        ? '<div class="msg">' . esc_html ($msg) . '</div>'
        : ''
    ;
}
```

Then just add the shortcode in the page content.

```
[myshortcode]
```